# Can any one suggest sample for Reachability check when wifi loss inter net connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability

I have added reachability into my project following things are working fine.
1.It Check successfully host request, wifi or mobile date active connection..
but i have tested the reachability of wifi with loss of internet connection , it may give the results like reachable via wifi...(example like you have active wifi connection but no internet received form wifi)

I did added NSTimers and achieved exact result, but i want to achieve the this thing by reachability so can anyone help to solve my issue...

Comment: You can try specifying reachability by host, but there's still no guarantee that it will work as you want.  Apple specifically states that reachability is an indicator, not a guarantee, in either direction.

Comment: Ya  @Avi i know this conditions , but my question is there any ways to achieve this with or with out reachability...because NSTimer will not the right way to do this action...

Comment: What is wrong with using a timer?

Comment: Already i have used 3 kind of modes using timers...it may getting process of app getting slow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer ,

I did not initialize timers just using completion blocks , but completion blocks with delay almost equal to NSTIMERS.

I have created api for reachability with all conditions..

just attach sample method to check the all conditions..

```
-(void) blocksWithReachabiltyCheck :(bool) r_Status
{
    __weak id weakSelf = self;
    callBack = ^{

        double delayInSeconds = 10.0;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

            id strongSelf = weakSelf;

            if (!strongSelf) {
                return;
            }
            // Schedule the timer again
            //callBack();
            [weakSelf targetMethod:r_Status];
        });

    };

    // Start the timer for the first time
    callBack();
}

-(void)targetMethod:(bool)sender
{
    NSString *remoteHostName = @"www.apple.com";
    // NSString *remoteHostLabelFormatString = NSLocalizedString(@"Remote Host: %@", @"Remote host label format string");
    //    self.remoteHostLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:remoteHostLabelFormatString, remoteHostName];
    // NSLog(@"%@",remoteHostLabelFormatString);
    self.hostReachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:remoteHostName];
    [self.hostReachability startNotifier];


    self.internetReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [self.internetReachability startNotifier];


    self.wifiReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
    [self.wifiReachability startNotifier];

    if (sender == YES)
    {
        callBack();
    }

}



  //stop timer
    -(void) RXStopNotifier
    {

        [self blocksWithReachabiltyCheck:NO];
    }
    //start notifier with host name
    -(void) RXStartNotifier:(NSString *)hostNameString
    {

        [self blocksWithReachabiltyCheck:YES];
        hostName  = hostNameString;
    }

@synthesize callBack;
@property (copy)__block void (^callBack)(void) ;

//Notification method
- (void) RXSeachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    if (timerFlag == false)
    {
        timerFlag = true;
        Reachability* curReach = [note object];
        NetworkStatus netStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];;
        statusReach = 0;

        switch (netStatus)
        {
            case NotReachable:        {
                NSLog(@"Not Access ");
                statusReach = 0;
                break;
            }

            case ReachableViaWWAN:
                //            {
                //                NSLog(@"Reachable WWAN");
                //                statusReach = 1;
                //                //            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"WWAN5.png"];
                //                break;
                //            }
            case ReachableViaWiFi:        {
                if (instantFlag == NO)
                {

                    NSLog(@"Reachable WIFI or Reachable WWAN");
                    NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:hostName] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:1];
                    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
                    NSError *error = nil;
                    [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
                    //NSLog(@"response %d", [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]);
                    if ([(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode] == 200) {

                        statusReach = 1;
                        NSLog(@"Success");
                    }
                    else
                    {


                        statusReach = 2;
                        NSLog(@"Failed");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    statusReach = 1;
                }
                break;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

if any one having doubts just reach me....

Answer (score 0):

i also had similar problem to detect if internet lost. example : you have connected to WIFI but internet is not active due to bill settlement or something.

If you are using AFNetworking there will be error code if you lost your internet connection while doing some POST request.

below is my code.

```
 AFHTTPSessionManager * manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager POST:@"" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

        //If response Sucess

    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@",error);

        if(error.code==-1009){
            // This Error Comes when internet is not active.
so inside this you can make any action
        }


    }];
```

Comment: Why are you checking Internet? if you are sending data to web service or getting data back to your device, you might be using AFNetworking . so in that you can use that above .in error section. just use `error.code==-1009`

Comment: I have tower kind of image on my app ...when ever networking not there i have to update the tower image ....